# MVC Passing ViewBag value from another controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, viewbag

I've set a value into `Viewbag.message` in my default HomeController and successfully display it in my `Shared/_Layout.cshtml`.

After that I added another TestController and in the TestController view, `Viewbag.message` seems to be null. May I know what's wrong with it.

Correct me if I'm wrong,from my understanding `Viewbag.Message` should be available from all over the places?

Comment: for that TestController view also you have to what you have done for Viewbag.message in my default HomeController

Answer (score 38, accepted):

ViewBag is a dynamic property that takes advantage of the new dynamic features in C# 4.0.
Basically it is a wrapper around the ViewData and also used to pass data from controller to corresponding view.

- It’s life also lies only during the current request. If redirection occurs then it’s value becomes null.
- It doesn’t required typecasting  for complex data type.

Below is a summary table which shows different mechanism of persistence.
[image: Summary of ViewBag and the other mechanism] [Credit:CodeProjectArticle](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/556995/Model-view-controller-MVC-Interview-questions-and)

Comment: using `TempData.Keep` will maintain the data from View to Controller and Controller to View.

Answer (score 13):

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    TempData["Message"] = "Success";
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}


public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.Message=TempData["Message"];
    return View();
}
```

Comment: As a side-note:  `The SessionStateTempDataProvider class requires session state to be enabled.`

Answer (score -2):

```
//one controller to another controller you need to use seesion 
//this is Home controller

[httpPost]
public actionresult Index()
{
    session["Message"] = "Welcome to session tutorial";
    return redirectToAction("Index","About");
}

//now pass to the another About controller

[httpPost]
public actionresult About()
{
    Viewbag.Message = session["Message"]
    return view();
}
```